# Multiple IP nfs mounts

Tags: nfs, systemd, automount

We have an enterprise file system that provides multiple IPs, server by several nodes.

Our clients are Ubuntu 20.04 mounting based on a DNS name that returns a set of IP addresses. This seems to work okay, as the addresses that get used across the system seem to be spread across the available IP addresses.

If an IP address fails, the client's don't seem to pick another one unless the mount is explicitly unmounted. Is there an option to make this happen automatically?

We are using systems automounts.

Comment: This is a long-standing problem with many NAS systems. Unless the NAS cluster knows enough to re-assign the IP address to a working node you're out of luck. You could put in a kludge to check each NFS mount periodically and unmount if the mount doesn't respond but you'll still get outages between the checks. This is one case where SMB mounts work better than NFS as they handle the round-robin in a more sane fashion.

Comment: @doneal24: It's probably because the SMB client also has to deal with DFS (pointers to another server), which necessitated the ability for the kernel to make DNS queries on its own, while NFS doesn't _really_ have an equivalent (I guess it does but it's nowhere near as widespread) so the NFS client stuck with 'mount.nfs' resolving the server address just once before mounting...